# How to play an mp3 file in Xcode from time t1 to t2 with AVAudioPlayer

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I wonder if there is a more elegant way to play a mp3 file with AVAudioPlayer Class, from t1 to t2 time without using NSTimers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**AVAudioPlayer** has a method `playAtTime:` which takes care of *t1*, however there's no easy way to stop playing at a specific time (*t2*).

As of **iOS8** **AVFoundation** has new api's such as **AVAudioEngine** and **AVAudioPlayerNode**. You may find implementing **AVAudioPlayerNode** instead is more suited for your requirements as it has a method named

```
- scheduleSegment:startingFrame:frameCount:atTime:completionHandler:
```

which is for playing a segment of an audio file.

Comment: thank you for advice. I will try  **AVAudioEngine** as my app's deployment target is **IOS8**.

Comment: you're welcome. Until ios8 I would use the Audio Toolbox framework with AudioQueueServices api for this sort of thing, but when AVAudioEngine was introduced I use it now. It's basically an obj-c wrapper for some of the lower level C apis in Core Audio such as AudioUnits.

Answer (score 1):

I tested below code and it works perfect within t1 and t2 time. But don't forget to define `AVAudioEngine *engine` in your class.

```
- (void) playAudioWithinT1: (float) t1 andT2:(float) t2{
//t1 and t2 are the seconds to play audio in between
NSError *error;
NSURL *urlForSoundFile;
float startingFrame;
float framesToPlay;

NSString *audioPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"_preview" ofType:@"mp3"];
urlForSoundFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioPath];
engine = [[AVAudioEngine alloc] init];
AVAudioPlayerNode *player = [[AVAudioPlayerNode alloc] init];
[engine attachNode:player];
AVAudioFile *file = [[AVAudioFile alloc] initForReading:urlForSoundFile
                                                  error:&error];
startingFrame = (t1 * file.processingFormat.sampleRate);
framesToPlay = (t2 * file.processingFormat.sampleRate - startingFrame);

AVAudioMixerNode *mainMixer = [engine mainMixerNode];
[engine connect:player to:mainMixer format:file.processingFormat];
[player scheduleSegment:file startingFrame:startingFrame frameCount:framesToPlay atTime:nil completionHandler:nil];
[engine startAndReturnError:&error];
[player play];
```

}